# Using Azure Compute to Replace Win2008 IIS server?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We are looking to replace our normal Win2008 R2 IIS server with a Azure Cloud based solution.   Our Current use scenario is something like this:

Server A
Hosts 7 Websites. 
All Websites are Managed and Maintained with Visual Studio 2010. They are Web Projects, not Web Services.  Each of the Sites has unique domain names. www.comanyA.com, www.companyB.com Intranet.companyB.com, etc.  There are three sites that are SSL enabled and have Verisign Certificates.

The Sites consist of many asp, aspx and image files. We also create file content on demand (Excel Exports) that users can then click to download.  We also make a Connection to a SQL Server for Back-end Data. We would need a Secure Connection to a SQL Azure DB and or an On-Premiss SQL Database (depending on when we move our SQL to SQL Azure).

I Would also need the same Security Permissions setup so all the users have the same permissions that they do for the Existing IIS Server. So I'd like Active Directly Integration.

I'd really rather not have a VM Image that is just running in the cloud. I don't want to have to maintain the OS level of stuff, (Updates, etc)

Is this something that Azure Compute can do for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not actually a single question. The only real question here that I see is

> "Is this something that Azure Compute can do for me?"

And answer is - depends :) To very high degree, Azure compute might and will help you!

To solve challenge #1 (Multiple Websites / no ssl) - the easieast. Check [this](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/) and [that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx) blog posts.

Challenge #2 (Connecting to SQL Azure / On-Premise SQL Server) - second easiest. SQL Azure still supports only [SQL Server Authentication and it requires encrypted connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394108.aspx). As for connecting to On-Premise SQL Server, you can use [Windows Azure Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg508836.aspx) (and [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-network/)). You can even [domain-join your compute instances in the cloud](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_azure_connect_team_blog/archive/2010/12/10/domain-joining-windows-azure-roles.aspx).

Challenge #3 (Active Directory integration) - part of it described in Challenge #2 - domain join your roles! But you could also review the [Windows Azure Access Control Service and its ADFS integration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/plankytronixx/archive/2011/01/11/video-how-windows-azure-app-fab-acs-and-adfs-2-0-work-together.aspx).

Challenge #4 (Multiple SSL Enabled sites behind same endpoint). Well, this is the trickiest! In [Windows Azure everything lives behind a load balancer](http://blogs.staykov.net/2012/03/windows-azure-basics-part-2-of.html). So, you could generally define only one standard HTTPS (on port 443) endpoint. And that's it. Although, you could now have separate SSL certificate for each different SSL enabled site, this is not possible in Windows Azure. For this to work in Windows Azure, you need a Subject Alternative Name certificate ([here](http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm), [here](http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name-compatibility.htm) and [here](http://www.verisign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/subject-alternative-name-certificates/index.html) are just some examples).

Hope that this helps!